# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError presumably in driver program: Cannot save Word2Vec model

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, word2vec

Using Spark v1.6.0

I am trying to tryin word vectors on our cluster. However, I am getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception (see log output belog). The task has 40GB of RAM available and the input is a 5.5GB JSON file.

Since all stages are completing it's task I think that the problem arrives at the line

```
model.save(sc, outputFile)
```

of my program but I am not 100% sure about this and even if I was I would not know how I could avoid this problem. See the program skeleton below. I can provide the full sourcecode if needed - I removed the preprocessing part to simplify the code.

```scala
object Word2VecOnCluster {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val inputFile = new File(args(0))
    val outputDirectory = new File(args(1))
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word2VecOnCluster")

    if(args.length > 2) {
      conf.setMaster(args(2))
    }

    outputDirectory.mkdirs()

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val file = sc.textFile(inputFile.getAbsolutePath)

    val wordSequence = file
      .repartition(500)
      .mapPartitions( lineIterator => {
          // Does some preprocessing ..
      })    
      .map(line => line.split("\\s+").toSeq)

    val word2vec = new Word2Vec()    
    val model = word2vec
      .setNumPartitions(500)
      .fit(wordSequence)

    val outputFile =  outputDirectory.getAbsolutePath + File.separator + inputFile.getName
    model.save(sc, outputFile)

    System.exit(0)    
  }
}
```

This is the log output after the last tasks of stage 2.0 finish:

```
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 428.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 970) in 701 ms on node12.hadoop.company.at (499/500)
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 439.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 981) in 680 ms on node12.hadoop.company.at (500/500)
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 2.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (collect at Word2Vec.scala:170) finished in 2.356 s
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at Word2Vec.scala:170, took 439.713694 s
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO Word2Vec: trainWordsCount = 685345162
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.9 KB, free 357.7 KB)
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 KB, free 361.7 KB)
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.95:42051 (size: 4.0 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 4 from broadcast at Word2Vec.scala:290
16/04/06 12:06:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 150.6 MB, free 150.9 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 154.9 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.95:42051 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 507.1 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece1 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 158.9 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece1 in memory on 192.168.0.95:42051 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 503.1 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece2 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 162.9 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece2 in memory on 192.168.0.95:42051 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 499.1 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece3 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.9 MB, free 165.8 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece3 in memory on 192.168.0.95:42051 (size: 2.9 MB, free: 496.2 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from broadcast at Word2Vec.scala:291
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6 stored as values in memory (estimated size 33.2 MB, free 199.0 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.0 MB, free 203.0 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.95:42051 (size: 4.0 MB, free: 492.2 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6_piece1 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 870.5 KB, free 203.9 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece1 in memory on 192.168.0.95:42051 (size: 870.5 KB, free: 491.3 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:35 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 6 from broadcast at Word2Vec.scala:292
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:742)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec$$anonfun$fit$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Word2Vec.scala:329)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:328)
    at masterthesis.code.wordvectors.Word2VecOnCluster$.main(Word2VecOnCluster.scala:112)
    at masterthesis.code.wordvectors.Word2VecOnCluster.main(Word2VecOnCluster.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 192.168.0.95:42051 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 491.3 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node10.hadoop.company.at:36555 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node04.hadoop.company.at:33602 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node13.hadoop.company.at:53455 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node11.hadoop.company.at:50336 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node02.hadoop.company.at:52435 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node06.hadoop.company.at:49865 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node09.hadoop.company.at:44672 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node01.hadoop.company.at:33026 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node14.hadoop.company.at:38802 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node03.hadoop.company.at:48959 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node12.hadoop.company.at:60505 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node05.hadoop.company.at:43832 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node07.hadoop.company.at:56636 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node08.hadoop.company.at:51583 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on node15.hadoop.company.at:41850 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 2
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 192.168.0.95:42051 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 491.3 MB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node14.hadoop.company.at:38802 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node05.hadoop.company.at:43832 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node12.hadoop.company.at:60505 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node08.hadoop.company.at:51583 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node03.hadoop.company.at:48959 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node15.hadoop.company.at:41850 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node07.hadoop.company.at:56636 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node13.hadoop.company.at:53455 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node06.hadoop.company.at:49865 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node10.hadoop.company.at:36555 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node04.hadoop.company.at:33602 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node02.hadoop.company.at:52435 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node09.hadoop.company.at:44672 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node11.hadoop.company.at:50336 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on node01.hadoop.company.at:33026 in memory (size: 2.2 KB, free: 28.5 GB)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 1
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.0.95:4040
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3f6c9bf3-be08-4eac-bc12-f6110beedb60
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3f6c9bf3-be08-4eac-bc12-f6110beedb60/httpd-cc65e6a2-705b-4da0-8845-54992f85ddb8
16/04/06 12:06:38 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
```

As you can see, the stages finish which points to the driver program. Please ignore "*(1 failed)*" this is just a idiosyncratic node that refuses to work sometimes at the moment ^^

[image]

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Looking at the line "at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:328)" I assume that the error was caused by the model.fit. Could it be that it retried the failed task later on?

Comment: @NiekBartholomeus No, I killed the job after that. I think the problem might be that the actual model is extremely large. It appears that there are 700 million words in the end (`trainWordsCount = 685345162`) that means 700 million times 100 dimension times 4 or I think even 8 bytes. I think that could indeed cause a problem here..

Comment: @NiekBartholomeus Butthen again, Googles word2vec model with 300 dimensions has I think something around 3,5GB in size if I recall that right ... :/

Comment: if I'm not mistaking the word2vec algorithm doesn't need to keep the whole co-occurrence matrix in memory, so I would say your 40GB of RAM should largely be sufficient for a corpus of 5GB. Did you specify enough memory for the spark driver and/or executor? Can you monitor the RAM and verify that it is all being used during the training?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? We thought we faced something similar (though less data and less memory) and ended up using ".ml." implementation, but in our case it was really some problem in saving the model (on cluster). The problem in your case is probably indeed in the fit process, since the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2Vec.scala) shows building Arrays like `val syn1Global = new Array[Float](vocabSize * vectorSize) `, thus OOM errors possible.

Comment: @briadeus If I remember correctly, this was due to an issue present in an earlier version (1.6.0 is I am not mistaken). I cannot try this now but this problem shouldn't be present in later versions.